# efficiently splitting one file into several files by value of column

Tags: python, shell, unix

I have a tab-delimited text file that is very large. Many lines in the file have the same value for one of the columns in the file (call it column k). I want to separate this file into multiple files, putting entries with the same value of k in the same file. How can I do this? For example:

```
a foo
1 bar
c foo
2 bar
d foo
```

should be split into a file "foo" containing the entries "a foo" and "c foo" and "d foo" and a file called "bar" containing the entries "1 bar" and "2 bar".

how can I do this in either a shell script or in Python?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure how *efficient* it is, but the quick and easy way is to take advantage of the way file redirection works in `awk`:

```
awk '{ print >> $5 }' yourfile
```

That will append each line (unmodified) into a file named after column `5`.  Adjust as necessary.

Comment: It's probably very efficient. If not, try mawk.

Comment: Only use the `>>` operator if you're appending onto an existing file. It's more "AWKish" to use the `>` operator which will create a new file or overwrite an existing one on the first write, but will append on subsequent writes during the same invocation (unless `close()` is called). Here's the way I'd do it: `awk '{print > "/path/to/" $5 ".extension"}' yourfile`

Comment: How can I do this in Python too?

Comment: I chose `awk` specifically for the feature that allows you to redirect to a string which automatically creates and then references a file handle.  Python could solve your problem, but not with such an elegant one-liner.

Comment: I've noticed that `awk` doesn't open files indiscriminatingly i.e. it has a builtin functionality similar to [`FileCache` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/FileCache.html): `perl -MFileCache -ane'print {cacheout ">>", $F[4]} $_' yourfile`

Answer (score 7):

This should work per your spec

```
awk '{outFile=$2; print $0 > outFile}' BigManegyFile
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can omit the `$0` since that's the default.

Comment: Yes, it's a tradeoff. In my mind it makes it more self-documenting, but I understand other viewpoints.

Answer (score 1):

After running both versions of the above awk commands (+ having awk error out) and seeing the request for a python version, I embarked on a short and not particularly arduous journey of writing a utility to easily split files based on keys.

Github repo: https://github.com/gstaubli/split_file_by_key

Background info: http://garrens.com/blog/2015/04/02/split-file-by-keys/

Awk error:

```
awk: 14 makes too many open files
 input record number 4555369, file part-r-00000
 source line number 1
```

Comment: Thanks Garren! I actually get the same error when trying to using python with a large file (Too many open files)... I am looking if there is any way to solve starting from your work.

Comment: @user971102 I recently refactored that utility to no longer require a sorted input file. I presume you tried my newest change which keeps all open file writer in memory. Two ways to alleviate this problem: try my old version (which would require a sorted input file by the keys to split). Or more ideally, I'll update the utility (or you can) to something like an LRU cache of recent files then reopen for existing files (as append), replacing the oldest file writer in the cache.

Comment: Your older version with sorted data works like a charm :) thanks so much!!

Comment: @user971102 glad to hear it! I updated split_file_by_key to handle near unlimited files.