# Awk comparing 3 values, 2nd file value between 1st file values with multiple column printout between both files to a 3rd

Tags: python, bash, powershell, awk, sed

I am trying to make a comparison between two large files, tab delimited.  I have been trying to use awk & bash (Ubuntu 15.10), python (v3.5) and powershell (windows 10).  My only background is Java but my field tends to stick with the scripting languages.

I am trying to see

File 1  A[ ]

```
1   gramene gene    4854    9652    .   -   .   ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865;biotype=protein_coding;description=Uncharacterized protein  [Source:UniProtKB/TrEMBL%3BAcc:C0P8I2];gene_id=GRMZM2G059865;logic_name=genebuilder;version=1
1   gramene gene    9882    10387   .   -   .   ID=gene:GRMZM5G888250;biotype=protein_coding;gene_id=GRMZM5G888250;logic_name=genebuilder;version=1
1   gramene gene    109519  111769  .   -   .   ID=gene:GRMZM2G093344;biotype=protein_coding;gene_id=GRMZM2G093344;logic_name=genebuilder;version=1
1   gramene gene    136307  138929  .   +   .   ID=gene:GRMZM2G093399;biotype=protein_coding;gene_id=GRMZM2G093399;logic_name=genebuilder;version=1
```

File 2  B [ ]

```
S1_6370 T/C 1   6370    +
S1_8210 T   1   8210    +
S1_8376 A   1   8376    +
S1_9889 A   1   9889    +
```

Output

```
1   ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4857    9652    -   S1_6370 T/C 6370    +   
1   ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4857    9652    -   S1_8210 T   8210    +
1   ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4857    9652    -   S1_8376 A   8376    +
1   ID=gene:GRMZM5G888250   9882    10387   -   S1_9889 A   9889    +
```

My general logic

```
loop (until end of A[ ] and B[ ])
if
B[$4]>A[$4] && B[$4]<A[$5]  #if the value in B column 4 is in between the values in A columns 4 & 5.
then
-F”\t” print {A[1], A[9(filtered)], A[$4FS$5], B[$1], B[$2], B[$3], B[$4], B[$5]}   #hopefully reflects awk column calls if the two files were able to have their columns defined that way.
movea++ # to see if the next set of B column 4 values is in between the values in A columns 4 & 5 
else
moveb++ #to see if the next set of A columns 4&5 values contain the current vales of B column 4 in them.
```

I know this logic doesn’t follow any language that I am aware of but is similar in parts.  It seems like NR and FNR are two built in running values in awk.  Awk helped me split up File 2 that had 10 values in B[$1] into 10 files quite easily and also cut helped with cutting out the few hundred columns (~255+) beyond the 5 you see here.  Now I am working File 2 sizes around a couple MB instead of 1 file of 1.6 GB.  Other than cutting down loading times, I wanted to simplify the loops.  I haven’t backtracked to my previous attempts of python or powershell since I trimmed the file sizes down.  I convinced myself they just weren’t going to read my files with their built in libraries or cmdlets.  Which I’ll try sometime soon if I am unable to figure out an awk solution.

[comparing multiple files and columns using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305201/comparing-multiple-files-and-columns-using-awk) #referenced
[Awk greater than less than but within a set range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516044/awk-greater-than-less-than-but-within-a-set-range)  #referenced
[efficiently splitting one file into several files by value of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305132/efficiently-splitting-one-file-into-several-files-by-value-of-column)    #the one thing that worked
[Using awk to get a specific string in line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153582/using-awk-to-get-a-specific-string-in-line) #might be able to filter column 9
[How to check value of a column lies between values of two columns in other file and print corresponding value from column in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608870/how-to-check-value-of-a-column-lies-between-values-of-two-columns-in-other-file)    #this seemed the closest but without all the printing out in a third file I wanted, still not able to figure out the syntax completely

Comment: StackOverflow programming is the worst. You should be spending time learning the syntax of awk, python, or whatever, but you simply wasted your time by referencing loads of SO questions that will hardly help you learn the languages if you haven't even invested time in learning the basics. Also, re "I convinced myself..." You're simply wrong. 1.6 GB? A single Python string could handle that, let alone line processing.

Comment: `paste fileB fileA | awk ...` could be a good approach...

Comment: @anishsane No, there's no one to one correspondence between lines of the two files.

Comment: Oh, i misinterpreted it then...

Comment: The number 4857 appears in the desired output but it appears no where in the input.  Did you mean 4854?

Comment: (1) The sample output includes field 7 of file A but that is not shown under "general logic."  (2) The  sample output omits field 3 of file B but that field is included under "general logic."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=getline s <"B"; split(s,b,"\t")} !x{exit} {sub(/;.*/,"",$9); while (x && $4<b[4] && b[4]<$5){print $1,$9,$4,$5,$7,b[1],b[2],b[4],b[5]; x=getline s <"B"; split(s,b,"\t")}}' OFS='\t' A
1       ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4854    9652    -       S1_6370 T/C     6370    +
1       ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4854    9652    -       S1_8210 T       8210    +
1       ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4854    9652    -       S1_8376 A       8376    +
1       ID=gene:GRMZM5G888250   9882    10387   -       S1_9889 A       9889    +
```

#### How it works

This program implicitly loops through the lines of file A.

- `BEGIN{x=getline s <"B"; split(s,b,"\t")}`

  Before we start reading file A, read the first line of file B into string `s`.  Split that string up into array `b` using tabs as the separator.

  The function `getline` will set `x` to true until we run out of lines to read in file B.
- `!x{exit}`

  If we have run out of lines to read in file B, then `exit` the program.
- `sub(/;.*/,"",$9)`

  Remove everything after the `;` from field 9 of file A.
- `while (x && $4<b[4] && b[4]<$5){print $1,$9,$4,$5,$7,b[1],b[2],b[4],b[5]; x=getline s <"B"; split(s,b,"\t")}`

  Loop through the lines of file B, printing the requested output as long as the fourth field of line B is between the values of fields 4 and 5 of file A.

  The function `getline` will set `x` to true until we run out of lines to read in file B.
- `OFS='\t'`

  Make the output field separator a tab.

#### Multi-line version

For those who prefer their awk code split over multiple lines:

```
awk '

BEGIN{
    x=getline s <"B"
    split(s,b,"\t")
} 

!x {
    exit
} 

{   
    sub(/;.*/,"",$9)
    while (x && $4<b[4] && b[4]<$5) {
        print $1,$9,$4,$5,$7,b[1],b[2],b[4],b[5]
        x=getline s <"B"; split(s,b,"\t")
    }
}
' OFS='\t' A
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk based solution:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{
         b0[NR]=$0;
         b4[NR]=$4;
         b_count=NR;
         next;
       }
       {
           for(i=1;i<=b_count;i++)
              if((b4[i]>$4) && (b4[i]<$5)){
                  print $1, gensub(/;.*/,"",1,$9), $4, $5, b0[i]
              }
       }' OFS=$'\t' file_b file_a
```

Output:

```
1   ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4854    9652    S1_6370 T/C 1   6370    +
1   ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4854    9652    S1_8210 T   1   8210    +
1   ID=gene:GRMZM2G059865   4854    9652    S1_8376 A   1   8376    +
1   ID=gene:GRMZM5G888250   9882    10387   S1_9889 A   1   9889    +
```

Explanation:

1. `NR==FNR` First file - file_b
2. Record entire file in local arrays - b0 & b4
3. & skip the processing code for second file - `next`
4. For next file, compare & print the lines in required format.
5. `gensub` : A regex replacement function, used for formatting the 9th field in fileA. Alternate mechanisms like `split` functions are also possible.